# What's the semantics of ETCD_PEER_KEY_FILE in cloud-config

Tags: coreos, etcd

An `etcd` instance can have multiple peers. According to the [CoreOS doc](https://coreos.com/docs/distributed-configuration/customize-etcd-unit/) I can configure a parameter `ETCD_PEER_KEY_FILE=/path/to/peers.key`. If I interpret this parameter according to its name, I can put the private keys of a peer (or more peer_s_) in that file. What's the rational behind this? Can someone explain, what this parameter really *means* (didn't find any documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Documentation is [here](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/security.md#basic-setup)

`--cert-file=<path>:` Certificate used for SSL/TLS connections to etcd.

`--peer-cert-file=<path>:` Certificate used for SSL/TLS connections between peers. This will be used both for listening on the peer address as well as sending requests to other peers.